# Cannot download 3rd party maven artifacts via apache archiva

Tags: maven, archiva

I am not able to download 3rd party maven artifacts via apache archiva. I added third-party repository to archiva repositories and I created new Proxy Connector for it.

Do I need to do somehing more?

Could not resolve dependencies for project XXX Failure to find YYY ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you question, but here how i use third-party repos.
The third-party repo is a local repository like the snapshots and releases. I am uploading there all the jars, and resources that is not generating myself and is not in a public maven repository.
I am using nexus, but the idea should be the same.

Comment: Our archiva is set up as our in-house repository which acts as a proxy to 3rd party repos - by this I mean e.g. maven central, etc. But I need to add a new one which is not set up by default and for some reason that doesn't work. I have no previous experience with archiva but with other kinds of repos - Nexus, ...

Comment: you need tree things: Add a Remote Repository, then the proxy Connetor and finaly a Repository Group

Comment: I thought that proxy connector connects the remote repository to our internal repository and thats it